# Entity Framework, stored procedure, returning multiple temp tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

What is the easiest, simplest way to approach this issue. I have a complex stored procedure that returns two temp tables.

How can I get these tables to show in the entity framework edmx file? Or is such a thing not possible? End result I need both temp tables to be in a their own model. The SP accepts 2 arguments as inputs.

Currently I am using this method. But only one table returns and I get no column names as well. They only come back as an array objects. I have to manually map it to a model which is not ideal, tedious and hacky.

```
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("returnTwoTablesSP", connection);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataDateFrom", string.Empty);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataDateTo", string.Empty);

     List<TwoTableModel> tableList = new List<string>();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        reader.GetValues(values); // This returns the columns but just from 
                                     the 1st temp table only.
        var model = new TwoTableModel()
        {
            UserId = values[0].ToString(), //Each column field
            Name = values[1].ToString(),

        };

        tableList.Add(model);
    }
     return tableList;
```

Comment: Can you show the stored procedure?

Comment: The SP is much too long and also I may get in trouble for posting it however it returns two tables. One a header table with the names, dob, etc . The second is a detail table joined by the userid that has more detail about a person. The data in each is grabbed from various tables across the database

Comment: To read the next data set. `reader.NextResult();`

Comment: The NextResult does work however I do not know how to directly map the result with my Table1Model. Since the returned result is a collection of columns from different tables how do I create a database model from this? Currently I manually created a Table 1 and a Table 2 model that represents the columns that will be returned from the SP. It is a total of 75 columns. If I go line by line and set each column in my model manually it looks tacky. Is there any way I can map the columns from the sp into the properties of my Table1.cs and Table2.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NextResult() to get to the next table returned by your stored procedure.

```
reader.NextResult();
```

More info and a very nice example on how to configure it for your edmx or code first can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: The NextResult does work however I do not know how to directly map the result with my Table1Model. Since the returned result is a collection of columns from different tables how do I create a database model from this? Currently I manually created a Table 1 and a Table 2 model that represents the columns that will be returned from the SP. It is a total of 75 columns. If I go line by line and set each column in my model manually it looks tacky. Is there any way I can map the columns from the sp into the properties of my Table1.cs and Table2.cs